# Web api route doesn't support get with ?query

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, asp.net-web-api2

In the Web api route, it only support `api/Search/{query}`
However, almost all the jQuery plugin ajax using `api/Search?query=6`
What should I change to make the web api rout works with `?query=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I found it.
Here is the solution:

api/Search/{query?}